# Android ad-hoc / access point connection capabilities

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth, wifi, adhoc

I am looking for the best, if any, programmatic way of connecting two or more Android phones to each other through the use of either Bluetooth or preferably, Wi-Fi.  Apparently Android devices still do not have ad-hoc Wi-Fi capabilities and I am trying to create a peer based program without the use of any central server.

I want to accomplish this without the use of modification to the phones (no rooting).  It is even fine to have a phone act as an access point with no Internet access to its clients if that is possible, I just need a mobile network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't directly through the SDK.  Some phones / revisions may have factory or other support to do so, but you can't rely on the SDK to do this.

Comment: pleeeeease can you name me some names of these phones that support ad-hoc networking

Answer (score 2):

I have 2.2 on my Android phone and it does have tethering - it can create a wireless access point then other devices can connect to it.

To prevent it having the internet, just turn mobile internet off.

Comment: Your phone isn't rooted?  Where in the Android SDK is this feature available?

Comment: Not sure if it's in the SDK, but I know if I go to Menu -> Settings -> Tethering & Portable hotspot I can create one!

Comment: I'm sorry, but in my question I said I need to create a peer based program, I can't rely on users using external programs and features not available on all android devices.